# Creating route53 geolocation record using cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, infrastructure-as-code

I'm able to create a simple A record, but am having trouble creating one of the geolocation routing variety even after looking at AWS' documentation. With my code, I just end up with 2 A records. I have -

```
vRoute53Records:
  - groupName: 'TestGroup'
    records:
      - name: 'some-a-record'
        type: 'A'
        ttl: '60'
        values:
          - 'X.X.X.X'
      - name: 'some-geolocation-record'
        type: 'A'
        ttl: '60'
        setId: 'geolocation'
        values:
          - 'X.X.X.X'
        GeoLocation: 
          - CountryCode = "US"
```

Can someone help me correct my CloudFormation code?
Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

It is *expected* that you end up with multiple A records.

When you view the records in the Route53 web interface, be sure to go to the Preferences (the gear icon) and enable the "Routing policy" and "Differentiator" columns, so you can see which version of the A record is the default one and which one is the one that points elsewhere based on the GeoLocation of who queries it.